# what's the best way to evaluate Helsinki model with the Huggingface Trainer

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface

I am trying to finetune Helsinki model with the Huggingface trainer based on the documentation found under [link 1](https:////https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter7/4?fw=pt#:%7E:text=The%20score%20can%20go%20from,100%2C%20and%20higher%20is%20better.) and [link 2](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/translation) for a translation task from German to French. I am using cross validation for performance check. I am finetuning the model in aws Sagemaker notebook. I am noticing that the performance while training is working just fine but during evaluation the performance decreases dramatically from 2.7 iter/s (during training/finetuning) to 0.07 iter/s (during validation).

This is the code I am trying to finetune with:

```
#checkpoint
checkpoint = "Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-de-fr"
source_lang = "de"
target_lang = "fr"
prefix = "Übersetzen Deutsch ins Französisch: "

#dataset
dataset_opus100 = load_dataset("opus100", "de-fr", split="test")
final_corpus_dataset= dataset_opus100 
# preprocess
def preprocess_function(examples):
    inputs = [prefix + example[source_lang] for example in examples["translation"]]
    targets = [example[target_lang] for example in examples["translation"]]
    model_inputs = tokenizer(
        inputs, text_target=targets, max_length=128, truncation=True
    )
    return model_inputs
# metric
def postprocess_text(preds, labels):
    preds = [pred.strip() for pred in preds]
    labels = [[label.strip()] for label in labels]

    return preds, labels


def compute_metrics(eval_preds):
    preds, labels = eval_preds
    if isinstance(preds, tuple):
        preds = preds[0]
    decoded_preds = tokenizer.batch_decode(preds, skip_special_tokens=True)

    labels = np.where(labels != -100, labels, tokenizer.pad_token_id)
    decoded_labels = tokenizer.batch_decode(labels, skip_special_tokens=True)

    decoded_preds, decoded_labels = postprocess_text(decoded_preds, decoded_labels)

    result = metric.compute(predictions=decoded_preds, references=decoded_labels)
    result = {"bleu": result["score"]}

    prediction_lens = [
        np.count_nonzero(pred != tokenizer.pad_token_id) for pred in preds
    ]
    result["gen_len"] = np.mean(prediction_lens)
    result = {k: round(v, 4) for k, v in result.items()}
    # print(result)
    return result

# config_params
exp_name = "de-fr-helsinki"


seed = 42
kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
# K-fold Cross Validation model evaluation
for fold, (train_ids, val_ids) in enumerate(kfold.split(final_corpus_dataset)):
    # if fold==0 or fold==1:
    #     continue
    # metric
    metric = evaluate.load("sacrebleu")
    # arguments for training
    training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
        output_dir=f"test/huggingface_exps/{exp_name}/fold{fold}",
        evaluation_strategy="epoch",
        logging_strategy="epoch",
        # logging_steps=4,
        learning_rate=2e-5,
        per_device_train_batch_size=64,
        per_device_eval_batch_size=64,
        weight_decay=0.01,
        num_train_epochs=10,
        save_total_limit=2,
        save_strategy="epoch",
        load_best_model_at_end=True,
        predict_with_generate=True,
        fp16=False,
        push_to_hub=False,
        # tensorboard log directory
        logging_dir=f"test/huggingface_exps/{exp_name}/fold{fold}/runs",
        report_to=["tensorboard"],
        # dataloader_num_workers=2,
    )
    print("fold", fold)
    # reset tokenizer and model
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
    data_collator = DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(tokenizer=tokenizer, model=checkpoint)
    model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
    # select splits
    train_dataset = final_corpus_dataset.select(train_ids)
    eval_dataset = final_corpus_dataset.select(val_ids)

    # preprocess
    train_dataset = train_dataset.map(preprocess_function, batched=True)
    eval_dataset = eval_dataset.map(preprocess_function, batched=True)




    trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
        # train_dataset=Dataset.from_dict(train_dataset[:40]),
        # eval_dataset=Dataset.from_dict(eval_dataset[:20]),
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        data_collator=data_collator,
        compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
        # callbacks=[TensorBoardCallback]
        callbacks=[
            CombinedTensorBoardCallback,
            EarlyStoppingCallback(early_stopping_patience=3),
        ],
    )

    train_result = trainer.train()

    # compute train results
    metrics = train_result.metrics

    # print metrics history
    import os

    # Create the directory if it doesn't exist
    os.makedirs(f"test/huggingface_exps/{exp_name}/fold{fold}/", exist_ok=True)

    with open(f"test/huggingface_exps/{exp_name}/fold{fold}/console.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(trainer.state.log_history, f)
    #next
```

**Things I considered:**

1. GPU memory is enough to fit the process (14.5GB/15.5GB)
2. Reducing the batch size for the evaluation process didn't help
3. While training on sagemmaker I get this error  `` valueerror: This tokenizer cannot be instantiated. Please make sure you have `sentencepiece` installed in order to use this tokenizer `` in comparaison to the training process with `mt5-small`. I had to install sentencepiece with  `! pip install transformers[sentencepiece]`. I'm not sure if it reduces the performance during the evaluation process ( nothing regarding this was mentioned in the documentation)

**Packages I installed in this order:**

```
! pip install transformers==4.28.0
! pip install datasets
! pip install evaluate
! pip install torch
! pip install sklearn
! pip install tensorboard
! pip install sacrebleu
! pip install accelerate -U
! pip install transformers[sentencepiece]
```

Comment: If you are using sagemaker, are you using the estimator training jobs or just the sagemaker typing in the code in the notebook?

Comment: What is/are the errors you see when you run the code? Is it just a speed issue when validating? Or does the process get killed?

Comment: Most probably you'll get flagged as a "need more focus" since you're asking for "best-practices" or what is the best way. But here's an example of fine-tuning an NMT model with huggingface and OPUS model that might help you, https://www.kaggle.com/code/alvations/how-to-fine-tune-an-opus-mt-model/

Comment: @alvas I am not using the estimator training jobs. I don't get any errors, the performance drops dramatically like described from 2.7 iter/s (during training/finetuning) to 0.07 iter/s (during validation). So yes its speed issue when validating. The process doesn't get killed.

Comment: Please utilize a SageMaker Training Job rather than directly training on a Notebook/Studio instance. That can be difficult for heavier datasets and models.